# Solaris ps output interpretation

Tags: solaris, ps

I have a program that regularly forks and execs other programs.  Occasionally, the programs that it starts get stuck in their processing and new programs never seem to start processing.  We eventually kill a bunch of stuck programs and restart the program that forks/execs them and the issue seems to clear out.  The ps output of old/stuck programs (pre kill) and new/working (post restart) programs are different.  What can we interpret from the difference between "-ksh -c" and the perl process (pid 6212)?  They were invoked in exactly the same way; why is the ps output different?  Is there some resource we may be running out of?  Virtual terminals?

```
[me@unixbox1:~]> ps -ef | grep app_bld_rfh2
  appadm 23926     1  0 14:19:34 ?        0:00 -ksh -c /home2/app/eai/app_bld_rfh2.pl  APP.DOC.SERVICE
      me  9232  5237  0 14:38:09 pts/28   0:00 grep app_bld_rfh2
  appadm  2975     1  0 14:30:04 ?        0:00 -ksh -c /home2/app/eai/app_bld_rfh2.pl  APP.DOC.SERVICE
  appadm 17697     1  0 14:14:31 ?        0:00 -ksh -c /home2/app/eai/app_bld_rfh2.pl  APP.DOC.SERVICE
  appadm 11820     1  0 14:09:30 ?        0:00 -ksh -c /home2/app/eai/app_bld_rfh2.pl  APP.DOC.SERVICE
  appadm 29658     1  0 14:25:00 ?        0:00 -ksh -c /home2/app/eai/app_bld_rfh2.pl  APP.DOC.SERVICE
  appadm  6212     1  1 14:35:15 pts/2    0:47 /usr/local/bin/perl /home2/app/eai/app_bld_rfh2.pl APP.DOC.SERVICE
```

Comment: How do you launch these scripts, precisely ?

Answer (score 0):

You get the `-ksh` when it is invoked as the login shell, and my guess is that your perl script `/home2/app/eai/app_bld_rfh2.pl` starts with the line

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

Invoking `ksh -c /home2/app/eai/app_bld_rfh2.pl APP.DOC.SERVICE` will in turn execute `perl` based on the above *hash-bang*. That is the cause of the difference.

As to why it hangs, my guess is that it needs a pseudo-tty to run, so if you start it through `ssh` use the `-t` option to force pseudo-tty allocation.